# compare two columns of two files and give conditional

Tags: awk

File 1:

```
chr pos1 sample Gene
chr1 123 sample1 x
chr1 234 sample2 Y
chr2 345 sample2 z
```

File 2:

```
sample Gene chr pos1 
sample1 x chr1 123 
sample2 A chr1 234 
sample2 c chr3 123 
sample2 z chr2 345
```

I used `awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1,$2]++;next}A[$3,$4]'file1 file2` to get the common result, like wise i tried

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[FNR]=[$1,$2]++;next}{print A[$3,$4]==A[FNR] ? $0"\t"1 :$0"\t"0}' file1 file2
```

but getting error.

Comment: I think you missed the array name here `A[FNR]=[$1,$2]++` on the right side of `=`

Answer (score 1):

`print A[$3,$4]==A[FNR`]`

is wrong as in the firest action you used `FNR` as index and here you are using `$3,$4

```
`A[FNR]=[$1,$2]++;`
```

i didnt understand you use `++` here??

You should be using something line

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[FNR]=$0;}NR!=FNR{split(A[FNR],line); if (line[1] == $3 && line[2]==$4) print $0 1; else print $0 0}' file1 file2
```

which will give an output as

```
sample Gene chr pos1 1
sample1 x chr1 123 1
sample2 A chr1 234 1
sample2 c chr3 123 0
sample2 z chr2 345 0
```

Here for the first file, `NR==FNR` the entire line is copied to arrray `A` and for the second file when `NR!=FNR` the array is splited `split` and checked with `$3` and `$4`